# Jfloat to Float

Tags: android, android-ndk

Here's my function definition in Java:

```
public static native void ToucheBegan( float x, float y, int tapcount );
```

And here's my definition in CPP

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_templateApp_GL2View_ToucheBegan( JNIEnv *env, jfloat x, jfloat y, jint tap_count );
```

When I log:

From Java I send:

```
125.278595 496.842102 1
```

And In C++ I receive:

```
3.274879 125.278595 1140353994
```

Is there some sort of conversion that have to be done between a jfloat to float or jint to int?

TIA!

Answer (score 4):

You forgot implicit jobject/jclass argument that every JNI function has:

```
void JNICALL Java_com_android_templateApp_GL2View_ToucheBegan( JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jfloat x, jfloat y, jint tap_count );
```

So you were interpreting 'thiz' as 'x', 'x' as 'y' and 'y' as 'tap_count'.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any special conversion required.

Check that your C++ logging is acting as anticipated.  One way to do this is to assign known values to x,y, and tapcount within the C++ function and make sure they are being logged as expected.